# Prevent Prettier from breaking Python code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am writing some conditions in my django html file and upon every save, vs code Prettier rearranges my code but it's doing it the wrong way hence creating errors.
Here's an example of what it is doing.

```
{% if messages %} {% for message in messages %} {% if
  message.tags == 'error' %}
  <div class="error-message">{{ message }}</div>
  {% elif message.tags == 'success' %}
  <div class="success-message">{{ message }}</div>
  {% else %}
  <div class="text-center mb-3">{{ message }}</div>
  {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% endif %}
```

I tried modifying the ***settings.json*** with the following

```
"git.confirmSync": false,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "python.showStartPage": false,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins=pylint_django"],
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
  }
```

But it's still doing the same thing

Comment: Uninstall Prettier then, simple.

Comment: or exclude your django templates files directory/directories from prettier (I don't see why the reformatting would create errors though)